# Scrapy webcrawler bot fails to crawl through pages after hitting second page.

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

Alright, here's my issue, I'm working on a very basic spider to go through a bunch of pages and download them. I'm using scrapy in python 2.7 on windows.  I have the downloading bit down, my issue is that the spider will download the first page just fine, claim it got the second link, and then claim its done. What it should do is scan the next page, download it, and move to the following, until it runs out of pages.

I'm not sure of what exactly I'm doing wrong, other than what is happening seems to be this: bot runs, it hits the page defined in start URL, then it goes through, obtains the link for the second page (I've verified that the link it obtains works), saves the first page, and then... decides the spider has run its course. I can't figure out what the issue is. I get DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request, which might mean it's seeing the link it has to travel to as a duplicate and refusing to do anything with it, but I'm not sure if that's the case.

```
import scrapy
import os.path

class Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "allcrawl"
    start_urls = [
        "http://forums.somethingawful.com/showthread.php?threadid=3755369&userid=0&perpage=40&pagenumber=1",
        ]
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 1 
        self.wherewego = "Undefined"

    def parse(self, response):
        print self.counter
        urlthing = response.xpath("//a[@title='Next page']").extract()
        urlthing = urlthing.pop()
        newurl = urlthing.split()
        url = newurl[1]
        url = url.replace("href=", "")
        url = url.replace('"', "")
        url = "http://forums.somethingawful.com/" + url
        self.wherewego = url
        return scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_save)

    def parse_save(self, response):
        current = str(self.counter)
        self.counter = self.counter + 1
        filename = 'test main ' + current + '.html'
        pathname = "C:/Users/John/Programing/paradise/archive"
        complete = os.path.join(pathname, filename + '.html')
        with open(complete, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        f.close()
        return scrapy.Request(self.wherewego)
```

Comment: first you assign second page address to `self.wherewego = url` and you use it in `Request(url,..)` and later you use the same url again in `Request(self.wherewego)`. Try to use different url in `Request(self.wherewego)`

Comment: After attempting that, and also attempting dont_filter = True, I get a different bug, in this case, it locks itself into looking at the same page, when it should be pulling the link to the next page.

Progress though! Thanks!